# Rails find a user and render form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am working on a project. I have two models one is User(Devise) with roles and the Other is Merchant. All the application Users are stored in users table associated with there roles.
For the Merchant Part. I have getting some problem.
I am accepting Merchant Registration as Request. So, to send a merchant request application, user will provide their email address only and the application will check Users table to see if the email address has been registered or not. If it has been registered, it will send a message like "email address is already used and suggest to register for a user" else it will store the email address in session(or else) or and render a merchant request form. User will submit the application and the application. All the input fields along with the email address are stored in merchants table.

I tried but couldn't. So, please suggest me how to do this task.

```
    def create
    if params[:email] == User.find_by_email(params[:email])
        flash[:notice] = "Email address already in use!"
        redirect_to new_merchant_path
    else
        render 'form'
    end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you post the controller code that you tried? You're more likely to get quality answers with code in your post.

Comment: Thanks @trh, I updated the question with the controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if params[:email] == User.find_by_email(params[:email])
```

This line isn't doing what you think it is.  You're looking up a user in the database by the params[:email] but you're comparing the whole user object to params[:email].

```
def create
  #this returns true or false
  if User.exists?(email: params[:email])
    flash[:notice] = "Email address already in use!"
    redirect_to new_merchant_path
  else
    render 'form'
  end
end
```

Comment: It not working. For both the case its rendering form

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're close.

since

```
User.find_by_email(params[:email])
```

returns the user object when found on database and `nil` if don't

```
def create
  if User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    flash[:notice] = "Email address already in use!"
    redirect_to new_merchant_path
  else
    render 'form'
  end
end
```

will work for you.
As sugested you should store the result on a instance variable if you need to show the user on your view.

```
def create
  if @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    flash[:notice] = "Email address already in use!"
    redirect_to new_merchant_path
  else
    render 'form'
  end
end
```

Comment: Its not working, for the both case, its rendering 'form'

Comment: can you confirm the email on `params[:email]` is saved on database?

Comment: there are emails in my database

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is this.

```
def create
  if (@user = User.find_by(email: params[:email]))
    flash[:notice] = "Email address already in use!"
    redirect_to new_merchant_path
  else
    render 'form'
  end
end
```

Then you can use the @user variable in your `form.html.erb`

Comment: Its not working. Do you have any other solutions. Other logic using jQuery or else.